# Split a string starting with an underscore _ but not end with the same _

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, replace, split

I want to split the starting with `_` but not end with a same `_`

This is my input:

```js
const text = "I, ___________________________ (Photographer's Name), hereby grant _____________________________"
```

I have tried this but it returns multiple array lengths:

```js
let re = /_(.*?)_/;
let result = text.split(re);
console.log('result-------->>>>', result);
```

Expected array:

```js
[
  "I,", 
  "___________________________", 
  " (Photographer's Name), hereby grant ", 
  "_____________________________"
]
```

Comment: i want make custom markup for _

Answer (score 6):

This pattern `_(.*?)_` matches an underscore followed by the least amount of characters till the next underscore, which would split on pairs of `__`

As the `.*?` is non greedy, the capturing group (which will also be kept in the result) will be empty.

If you make it greedy, it would over match it until the last occurrence of an `_` and prevent showing the separate underscore parts.

---

You could split on for example matching 2 or more underscores `(_{2,})` *(one would also work, but you can specify the number accordingly)* in a capturing group to keep the value where you have split on, and remove the empty entries from the array.

```js
const text = `I, ___________________________ (Photographer's Name), hereby grant _____________________________`;
let re = /(_{2,})/;
let result = text.split(re);
console.log('result-------->>>>', result.filter(Boolean));
```

Comment: Alternatively, without use of `filter`, you could use `/_{2,}|[^_]+/g` with `match`: `console.log('result-------->>>>', text.match(/_{2,}|[^_]+/g))`. If you need to be wary of single underscore characters, the regex `/(?:(?!_{2}).)+|_{2,}/g` can instead be used